# Why is 'RunWorkerCompleted' executed on the wrong thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

In the following code, when the `BackgroundWorker` is launched, a `SynchronizationContext` *does* exist, but still, the **RunWorkerCompleted** handler is executed on a different thread than the `RunWorkerAsync()` and therefore throws an exception. Why?

<sub>And when the call to `tempForm` is removed it runs fine. (And the same for when substituting a `MessageBox` for a `Form` there.)</sub>

<sub>(The code shows a `Form`, launches a `BackgroundWorker` that references another Form **f1** after one second, and then shows this second Form **f1**.)</sub>

```
public static Form1 f1;
static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();


[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    f1 = new Form1();
    using (Form1 tempForm = new Form1()) tempForm.ShowDialog();
    //MessageBox.Show("A MessageBox won't cause the exception later. Only the Form does.");   
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null) throw new Exception("This is NOT thrown");
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    Application.Run(f1);
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f1, "Inside RunWorkerCompleted");
    //Throws: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
}

static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because you call the `RunWorkerAsync` from a default synchronization context. As a small example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var ctx1 = SynchronizationContext.Current; // returns null
    var form = new Form();
    var ctx2 = SynchronizationContext.Current; // returns a WindowsFormsSyncContext
    form.ShowDialog();
    var ctx3 = SynchronizationContext.Current; // returns a SynchronizationContext

    worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // wrong context now
}
```

It appears that instantiating a form associates a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` with the current thread. Interestingly after closing the form the associated synchronization context will be set to the default one, i.e. the one that uses the threadpool.

---

After some digging I found the reason for the - at a first glance - strange behaviour: the constructor of `Control` initializes the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` if necessary (see [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs#535)). Once you return from `ShowDialog` then there won't be any message loop, so `SynchronizationContext.Current` has to be reset, in this case to the default threadpool `SynchronizationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows UI is not thread safe and does not support multi-threading at all. For this reason there is a check as to which thread creates and later tries to manipulate the allocated graphics resources. To avoid the exception you **MUST** use the invoke pattern shown here:

```
if(InvokeRequired) 
{
    Invoke(worker_RunWorkerCompleted, sender, e);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(f1, "Inside RunWorkerCompleted");
}
```

The fact that a different thread runs the method is normal. The Windows Forms are constructed by the entrant thread which must be re-entrant, this means you should not block (infinitely loop) the thread that runs the program at first.

If you look closely, in `Main()` is a `Run()` method somewhere. This is done so that the creating thread is free to terminate while the form goes on living his own life on the desktop.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker events are designed to run on the thread that calls RunWorkerAsync, so if you call that from the UI thread then there's no need for InvokeRequired/Invoke.